# Querying parallel foreach result cause Null reference error

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I have a parallel foreach statement like below

```
  Parallel.ForEach(spacialRecords, (spacerecord) =>
                   {
                       List<MeterValue> dat = new List<MeterValue>();
                       var latitude = Geometry.Y;
                       var longitude = spacerecord.Geometry.X;
                       var timeStamp = spacerecord.Timestamp;

                       foreach (var wdItem in workingData)
                       {
                           RepresentationValue spaceMeteredValue = spacerecord.GetMeterValue(wdItem);
                           if (spaceMeteredValue != null && wdItem.Representation != null)
                           {
                               var objMeterValue = new MeterValue();
                               objMeterValue.key = wdItem.Representation.Code;
                               objMeterValue.value = spaceMeteredValue.Designator != null ? Convert.ToString(spaceMeteredValue.Designator) : "";
                               dat.Add(objMeterValue);
                           }
                       }

                       listSpacialRecords.Add(new
                       {

                           operationLogDataId = yieldMaster.OperationalLogDataModelResponse.Id,
                           order = deviceElement.Order,
                           totalDistanceTravelled = deviceElement.TotalDistanceTravelled,
                           totalElapsedTime = deviceElement.TotalElapsedTime,
                           uploadedOn = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
                           collectedOn = timeStamp.ToUniversalTime(),
                           cropId = "8296e610-c055-11e7-851e-ad7650a5f99c",
                           productId = productid,
                           latitude = latitude,
                           longitude = longitude,
                           deviceConfigurationId = deviceElement.DeviceConfigurationId,
                           operationDataId = deviceElement.OperationDataId,
                           spatialRecords = dat,
                           depth = depth,
                           timeStamp = timeStamp,
                           totaldata = totalRecordCount

                       });

                   });
```

listSpacialRecords is a dynamic type list and i am getting a huge number of data in listSpacialRecords. So here i am doing some filtering, for that i have added the below code

```
 listSpacialRecords = listSpacialRecords
                  .Skip(1)
                  .Aggregate(
                      listSpacialRecords.Take(1).ToList(),
                      (a, x) =>
                      {
                          if (x.timeStamp.Subtract(a.Last().timeStamp).TotalSeconds >= 10.0)
                          {
                              a.Add(x);
                          }
                          return a;
                      });
```

The code is outside of foreach loop. And when i execute this I am getting error like

```
Cannot perform run time binding on a null reference
```

But when i remove the parallel and use normal foreach loop the code works fine.

Note : I made a break point over and I found listSpacialRecords shows all the records properly, I have checked with quickwatch and upto last element data is available but still it fails

Can anyone help me to figure out what i the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
listSpacialRecords.Add(...);
```

I'm assuming that this method is not explicitly thread-safe (it won't be by default). All the threads are talking to the same `listSpacialRecords`.

The moment you do this inside `Parallel.ForEach`, you have a very risky thread race - if two threads are calling `.Add` at the same time, *all number of bad things can happen* - including data loss.

So: synchronize all calls to this `Add`. This *could* be as a simple as:

```
var newValue = new {
    operationLogDataId = yieldMaster.OperationalLogDataModelResponse.Id,
    // etc etc...
};                           .
lock(listSpacialRecords) {
    listSpacialRecords.Add(newValue);
}
```

There's also a `dat.Add`, but this `dat` is context-bound to each call, so shouldn't need synchronization.

Comment: Sure let me try this

Comment: cool working perfectly. One more doubt can you please tell me about the performance also? I have a huge data that is why i have used parallel foreach. So is there any performance issues with with locking mechanism ?? for do i get benefit of parallel here ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV if you have lots of data, I worry that putting them in a list may be a bad idea in the first place; note also that this *can change the order*, so if order matters: `Parallel.ForEach` is a bad idea. `Parallel.For` might be better (so on the `i`'th iteration you read from position `i` and write to position `i` in an array somewhere - won't even need locking). As for performance: there's an additional loop in your code that will dominate the actions, so conflicts over the `lock` will be very rare (but very harmful) - there shouldn't be any impact on performance, basically