# Are there any concurrency considerations if an object is passed to multiple asynchronous functions in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await, concurrency, thread-safety

So, I have a use case where I want to pass an object to async functions working concurrently. Each function will update different independent part of the object. So, my doubt is will this cause any concurrency problem with list?

```
class Error 
{
    public object fieldA;
    public object fieldB;
    public object fieldC;
}

var error = new Error();
var awaitedTasks = new List<Task>();

awaitedTasks.Add(funcA(error));  // this async function will update only fieldA
awaitedTasks.Add(funcB(error));  // this async function will update only fieldB
awaitedTasks.Add(funcC(error));  // this async function will update only fieldC

await Task.WhenAll(awaitedTasks);

private async Task funcA(Error error)
{
    error.fieldA = await FetchAFromDbAsync();
}

private async Task funcB(Error error)
{
    error.fieldB = await FetchBFromDbAsync();
}

private async Task funcC(Error error)
{
    error.fieldC = await FetchCFromDbAsync();
}
```

So, adding more context, here we are enriching error's different field in different function.

Comment: With the `awaitedTasks` list? No, the list is not involved with any concurrency.

Comment: This would be very easy to test, have you at least tried to run your code scenario?

Comment: @GSerg can you explain why? I can see three method calls which are returning obviously a task. Those tasks are added to the list and then the code waits until all of the tasks are completed. So there should be three methods running at the same time. Yes, we could discuss if this is async or parallel, but I think the question is not wrong.

Comment: Depends how "independent" they really are.

Comment: @SebastianS. These three methods that run in parallel operate on the `error` instance. They do not operate on the list. The list is operated on only by the thread that is starting those three tasks, which adds three elements there in an absolutely sequential fashion.

Comment: @GSerg Ahh sorry I read over the question regarding the list. My brain just changed the question regarding the error object what would make more sense. Of course there is no concurrency issue with the list, you are absolutely right.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller - I have tried locally but didn't found any error, but don't want to take to prod before knowing all consequences.

Comment: This is a classic case of [premature optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4832663/1690217) From the information you have provided it doesn't look like concurrency is an issue, there are far better patterns like continuation that are designed for this, but your solution might work. Knowing that your hypothetical example is not your actual code makes it hard to give you a definitive answer, but why not deal with the issue if you detect it or post your code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for some honest feedback on style and implementation, not just the concept of concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no thread-safety concern in the code that you've posted. That's because you are in full control of the `Error` class, and so you can be absolutely sure that there is no shared internal state mutated as part of using the public API of this class. Things would be different if the `Error` was an external class to which you had no control. For example it would be unsafe and incorrect to use this pattern if the class was implemented like this:

```
class Error 
{
    private List<string> _logs = new();

    private object _a;
    public object A
    {
        get => _a;
        set { _a = value; _logs.Add("Property A updated"); }
    }

    private object _b;
    public object B
    {
        get => _b;
        set { _b = value; _logs.Add("Property B updated"); }
    }
}
```

Mutating the internal shared state `_logs` from multiple threads, could cause [all sorts of mayhem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865816/querying-parallel-foreach-result-cause-null-reference-error) to occur.

In general it's a good idea to be cautious about interacting with any object from multiple threads concurrently without synchronization, unless the object belongs to a class that is explicitly documented to be thread-safe. Personally I would avoid the pattern shown in your question, and I would prefer to aggregate all the values first, and then finally update all the properties of the `Error` object sequentially on a single thread:

```
Task<object> taskA = funcA();
Task<object> taskB = funcB();
Task<object> taskC = funcC();
await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB, taskC);

Error error = new();
error.A = taskA.Result;
error.B = taskB.Result;
error.C = taskC.Result;
```

Comment: i have explored same also, but problem with this is whenever a new field will be added, I have to again do 
       error.D = taskD.Result;
So, I will need to change this class.

Thus, to avoid same I want to enrich rather than a pure function, which returns data.

Comment: @Anuj you could take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69140421/updating-different-properties-of-same-object-in-parallel-invoke-is-thread-safe/69141683#69141683 "Updating different properties of same object in Parallel.Invoke is thread-safe?"), specifically at the `ObjectInitializer` class, that might give you some ideas. Or a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69416885/avoid-checking-condition-twice-when-assigning-from-task-awaited-with-task-whenal/69417690#69417690).

Answer (score 0):

To be really sure, you should show us what the three methods really do. I assume some simple code like this:

```
private async Task funcA(Error error)
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  error.fieldA = "funcA finished";
}

private async Task funcB(Error error)
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  error.fieldB = "funcB finished";
}

private async Task funcC(Error error)
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  error.fieldC = "funcC finished";
}
```

In that case, you are safe. But if the methods access shared variables, you might get some trouble. But this can only be judged if we see your complete code.

Comment: Updated code for more reference, I am passing an object to multiple functions each of which will basically enrich an independent field.

Comment: In that case, there are no concurrency errors to expect.